# EF Core says no service for type 'MyDatabaseProviderServices' has been registered

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am writing a database provider for Entity Framework Core 1.1.2, and I have the following issue.

I have an AddEntityFrameworkMyProvider() extension method (on IServiceCollection) which I think is called properly. In this method I register my own database provider.

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IDatabaseProvider, 
            DatabaseProvider<MyDatabaseProviderServices, MyDatabaseOptionsExtension>>());
```

However when I want to use my provider, I get an InvalidOperationException saying *No service for type 'MyDatabaseProviderServices' has been registered*.

Based on the callstack, this exception occurs at a `GetRequiredService<MyDatabaseProviderServices>()` function call.

It is interesting that MyDatabaseProviderServices' constructor is never called, so I am not so surprised by this exception. Am I right, and do I know well that an object of this type should be instantiated?

By the way, I try to follow the officially recommended EFCore 1.1 database provider "guideline" doing everything the same way: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2016/11/11/so-you-want-to-write-an-ef-core-provider/ What can this problem be?